# Compute the average of the same index in the list, python

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
A= [('1', 3), ('2', 7), ('3', 5), ('1', 7), ('2', 5), ('3', 1)]
```

From the list `A`, I would like to generate the output list like this:

```
Average = [('1', 5), ('2', 6), ('3', 2)]
```

Any tips would be really grateful! =)

Comment: how do you compute your average for the "3" key ?

Comment: @Cédric: I'd assume it is a typo. Any other value is indeed the average.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
a = [('1', 3), ('2', 7), ('3', 5), ('1', 7), ('2', 5), ('3', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in a:
    d[k].append(v)
avg = [(k, sum(v) // len(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems()]
print avg
```

prints

```
[('1', 5), ('3', 3), ('2', 6)]
```

Note that this uses integer division to compute the averages.  You might want to use floating point division instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your tip! :) Yes, I was thinking of how to use floating point division here.... any tips?  Again, thanks so much!! :)

Comment: @maria: Use `sum(v, 0.0) / len(v)` instead of `sum(v) // len(v)`.

Comment: @ Sven: can I ask you one more question? when I put float number as a value, it doesn't work. for example,>>> print result
{'1': [3.2, 7.3, 4.2], '3': [5.2, 1.6, 6.3], '2': [7.7, 5.1, 2.5]}
>>> avg = [(k, sum(v, 0.0) / len(v)) for k, v, in result.iteritems()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: @maria: Can't reproduce the error -- [it seems to work fine](http://ideone.com/b6ESr).  (Please click the link.)  Maybe you overwrote the built-in `sum()` function by a variable of the same name?

Comment: Got it. For some reason, it didn't work in the one server while it works in the other server. I guess it happened due to the different python version. Thank you so much for your wonderful help Sven! :D

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way :

```py
result = {}
for key, value in A:
   result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print [(k, sum(v) // len(v) for k,v in result.iteritems()]
```

Comment: If you're always using `setdefault` then a `defaultdict` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @agf: I don't agree.  In this case, code readability of both versions is the same, and this version is shorter and faster.

Comment: @agf : right, let's say I'm compatible with python2.4 and older ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you like to abstract code and reuse patterns? If that's the case, this `group` function is a useful pattern to have in your toolset. It's similar to [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but it works with non-consecutive elements and categorizes/maps in a single iteration (credits for the idea to Ruby Facets' [map_by](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map_by)):

```
def group(seq, callback=None):
    result = {}
    for category, item in (callback(seq) if callback else seq):
        result.setdefault(category, []).append(item)
    return result 

average = dict((k, sum(vs)/len(vs)) for (k, vs) in group(xs).items())
print(average)
# {'1': 5.0, '3': 3.0, '2': 6.0}
```

Answer (score -1):

One-liner.

```
a= [('1', 3), ('2', 7), ('3', 5), ('1', 7), ('2', 5), ('3', 1)]
map(lambda f:(f[0][0], (lambda g:sum(g)/len(g))(f[1])), map(lambda e:zip(*e), map(lambda c:filter(lambda d:d[0]==c, a), set(map(lambda b:b[0], a)))))
```

Comment: Your code is clever and I'm sure it was fun to write, but you get a -1 for succumbing to one-liner-itis.  Also, this code will be inscrutable to many.  And terribly inefficient.